# multiple models in cplex - python

Tags: python-3.x, variables, constraints, cplex, docplex

I want to implement the epsilon constraint method, where I need to have multiple models with similar variables and almost identical constraints. I was wondering how I can define a variable (or constraint) that I can use in all models. For example, please assume that I want to add a binary variable "x" and "con1" to two models ("mdl1" and "mdl2"). I have coded this problem as below, but it is not working. Would you please help me?

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

# Model names
mdl1 = Model("OBJ1")
mdl2 = Model("OBJ2")

# set_idx1 is defined here.

# Variables
x = mdl1.binary_var_dict(set_idx1, name="x")
x = mdl2.binary_var_dict(set_idx1, name="x")
```

Moreover, how should I define constraints to prevent duplicate efforts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In [Optimization easy with python](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/)

let me share the example [clone a linear model](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooclone.py)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve(log_output=False,)

mdlclone=mdl.clone()
mdlequal=mdl;


# set upper bound for nbbus40 to 0
nbbus40.ub=0

mdlclone.solve(log_output=False,)
mdlequal.solve(log_output=False,)


print("clone")
for v in mdlclone.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print("= operator")
for v in mdlequal.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

which gives

```
clone
nbBus40  =  6.0
nbBus30  =  2.0
= operator
nbBus40  =  0
nbBus30  =  10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

About using a modeling artefact in different models: this is not possible, each artefact belong to one parent model. Why would you want to do it?

About the second question, in order to avoid code duplication in writing a complex constraint (and you are right about this), I suggest writing a *function* that takes (at least) the model as argument, plus other input arguments.

A very simple example:

```
def new_ct_sum1(mdl, x, y):
    # returns a constraint stating x+y ==1
    # assumes x,y are in model mdl, otherwise an error is raised.
    return mdl.add(x + y == 1)
```